# Loop not overriding style of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, background-image

```js
function lineComplete() {
  let line = document.getElementById("line");
  for (let percentage = 0; percentage <= 100; percentage++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      line.style.width = `${percentage}%`;
    }, percentage * 25);
    if (percentage === 100) {
      undo();
    }
  }

  function undo() {
    for (let percent = 100; percent >= 0; percent--) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        line.style.width = `${percent}%`;
      }, percent * 25);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#outLine {
  width: 60%;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f12711, #f12711);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#line {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f12711, #f5af19);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="lineComplete()">
  <div id="outLine">
    <div id="line"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

In the above snippet, I am trying to show a loader-like effect which I am able to achieve. The problem is that when the width of `line` is 100%, I am trying to fire the function `undo`. This also works fine. There is a loop in `undo` which decreases the width of `line` and gradually bring its width to 0%. The loop also works fine as I have tried to run it after replacing its contents with `alert()` and it worked fine. But with the present situation, the loop is not resizing the `line`. I think that it is not able to override the styles.

Comment: What is expected result and what is actual result? Looks reasonable to me right now

Comment: @mplungjan Expected result: the width of `line` increases from 0 to 100% then again decrease to 0%. Actual result: width only increases, not decreases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function lineComplete() {
  let line = document.getElementById("line");
  for (let percentage = 0; percentage <= 100; percentage++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      line.style.width = `${percentage}%`;
      if (line.style.width === "100%") {
          undo();
      }
    }, percentage * 25);
  }

  function undo() {
    for (let percent = 100; percent >= 0; percent--) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        line.style.width = `${100 - percent}%`;
      }, percent * 25);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#outLine {
  width: 60%;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f12711, #f12711);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#line {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f12711, #f5af19);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="lineComplete()">
  <div id="outLine">
    <div id="line"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The problem was that when you decrease, the later iterations are scheduled to run earlier than the earlier iterations. Let's negate percentage `(100 - percentage)` and it will work.

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify your code like this. No forloop and setTimeout needed.

```js
function lineComplete() {
  let line = document.getElementById("line");
  line.classList.add("active");

  line.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
    line.classList.remove("active");
  });
}
```

```css
#outLine {
  width: 60%;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f12711, #f12711);
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#line {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f12711, #f5af19);
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: 2s linear;
}

#line.active {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body onload="lineComplete()">
    <div id="outLine">
      <div id="line"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Also can be done with only animations:

```css
#outLine {
  width: 60%;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f12711, #f12711);
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#line {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f12711, #f5af19);
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: 4s linear;
}

#line.active {
  animation: linecomplete 2s linear forwards;
  /*                                you can use "infinite" instead of "forwards" if you want */
}

@keyframes linecomplete {
  50% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="outLine">
  <div id="line" class="active"></div>
</div>
```